# Real Hyperbolic Plane $\mathbb{RH}^2$ as Homogenous Space

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Let us define the real hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{RH}^2$ to be the dual symmetric space of non-compact type for the compact symmetric space $S^2=SO(3)/SO(2)$.
For a symmetric space $G/K$ with Cartan decomposition $\mathfrak{g=k \oplus p}$, the dual symmetric space is given as the space $G'/K$ which has Cartan decomposition $\mathfrak{g'=k \oplus \sqrt{-1} p}$.
In the case of $S^2$, i.e. $G=SO(3)$ and $K=SO(2)$, this leads to $G' \simeq SO(2,1)$ and the symmetric space $SO(2,1)/SO(2)$.
So, to summarize:
$\mathbb{RH}^2=SO(2,1)/SO(2)$.
(This argument is presented, for example, in Helgason: *Differential Geometry, Lie Groups, and Symmetric Spaces*, p. 238)

Now here is what confuses me:
I have seen $\mathbb{RH}^2$ as a homogenous space denoted as $SL(2)/SO(2)$, for example here:
Berndt, Console, Enrique: *Submanifolds and Holonomy, Second Edition*, p. 350. 
$SL(2)$ and $SO(2,1)$ are not isomorphic, despite the exceptional isomorphism $\mathfrak{so}(3) \simeq \mathfrak{sl}(2)$.
So, my question is:

> What is $\mathbb{RH}^2$ as a homogenous space?

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "is (...) a homogeneous space". For the moment is as senseless as asking whether a set of 4 elements is a group.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking. By "as a homogenous space" I mean an isometry to a manifold of the form $G/K$, where $G$ is a Lie group and $K \subset G$ is a closed Lie subgroup, endowed with the bi-invariant metric obtained from the negative of the Killing form.

Comment: Yes this is what I asked (this is a very restrictive definition for homogenous space, but at least it's a definition)

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that $H^2= SO(2,1)/SO(2)$, as
$SO(2,1)$ is not connected. Furthermore the action of $SL(2,R)$ on $H$ has a kernel, $\pm Id$, so that $H^2= PSL(2,R)/PSO(2)$, not $SL(2)/SO(2)$

In fact $PSL(2,R)$ is isomorphic to $SO_0(2,1)$ by the following argument :
$SL(2,R)$ acts on the vector of $(3,3)$ symmetric real matrices. This vector space has a natural invariant quadratic form of signature $(2,1)$, and the kernel of the action is $\pm Id$. In this langage the hyperbolic plane is identify with the set of positive definite quadratic form with discrimant 1.

One checks that the map $PSL(2,R)$ to $S0 _0(2,1)$ is a bijection using the following observation. A positive definite quadratic form can be written as $q(x,y) = x^2+  y^2$ in some base of determinant 1. In this base, the Cartan involution around $q$ is the image in PSL(2) of the linear map $x\to y$, $y\to -x$.

The image of $PSL(2)$ contains all Cartan involutions, and is therefore surjective ; injectivity is easy to check.

Comment: $H^2$ "is" $SL(2)/SO(2)$ although it's not a faithful representation as homogeneous space. It's quite fortunate that the formalism of actions allows non-faithful actions (otherwise passing to an invariant subset behaves badly).  On the other hand it's correct that it's not $SO(2,1)/SO(2)$ since the latter homogeneous space has 2 components.

Comment: @YCor what do you mean when you write "$H^2$ 'is' $SL(2)/SO(2)$"? If I define $H^2$ to be the space modeled on one sheet of the hyperboloid or the upper half plane, wouldn't $SL(2)/SO(2)$ then be a double cover of that?

Comment: @user538044 No, $SL(2)$ acts isometrically transitively on $H^2$ with $SO(2)$ being the stabilizer of a point, so this yields an identification of $H^2$ with $SL(2)/SO(2)$.

Comment: I agree with ycor. Let me add that these description of the plane are not satisfactory. The isometry group of the hyperbolic plane is $PGL(2,R)$, (it contains reflexions) and $H^2=PGL2(R)/PO(2)$

Comment: Thank both of you, I now understand more than before, but not everything. I have $H^2=SO_0(2,1)/SO(2)$ by my definition of $H^2$. I have $H^2=PSL(2,R)/SO(2)$ by the exceptional isomorphism explained in @Thomas answer. I have the canonical projection $SL(2,R)/SO(2) \rightarrow PSL(2,R)/SO(2)$, which is a double cover. $SL(2,R)/SO(2)$ (or $PSL(2,R)/PSO(2)$) is the hyperbolic space modeled on the upper half plane. $SO_0(2,1)/SO(2)$ is the hyperbolic space modeled on one sheet of the hyperboloid. There is some isometry between the two models, but we haven't mentioned it yet, is that right?